# ResizableBox is displaying nothing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm experimenting with `react-resizable`, but this extremely basic example will simply display the text `XYZ` in the browser, but will otherwise be blank with no error messages. I am expecting a resizable box.

```
import { ResizableBox } from 'react-resizable';

import 'react-resizable/css/styles.css';

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <ResizableBox className="box" width={200} height={200} axis="y">
            <span className="text">XYZ</span>
        </ResizableBox>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I derived this test case from the [longer example here](https://github.com/react-grid-layout/react-resizable/blob/master/examples/ExampleLayout.js).

**EDIT**: And here is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-bogdan-08f01?file=/src/App.js

[image]

Comment: can you please provide the code sandbox link?

Comment: Your example does seem to work? I made the following sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-moore-esqrj?file=/src/App.js

Comment: as @MaartenDev told its working fine so please check your internal code

Comment: @MaartenDev It doesn't work? I just see plain text only with no resizable box at all.

Comment: @NishargShah It doesn't work for me. Do you see a resizable box? I just see plain text only.

Comment: I didnt see the results, let me check

Comment: There is a resizable box, you have to drag it down using the gray arrow in the bottom right corner. Because of the `axis="y"` you can only drag it down using the gray arrow

Comment: @MaartenDev Yes you're right. My eyesight is just bad!!! my gosh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply CSS styles with the `className` property. Here is a working example:

```
import React from "react";
import { ResizableBox } from "react-resizable";
import "react-resizable/css/styles.css";
import "./style.css";

const Box = () => {
  return (
    <ResizableBox
      className="box borderBlack"
      width={200}
      height={200}
      axis="y"          
    >
      <span className="text">XYZ!!</span>
    </ResizableBox>
  );
};

export default Box;
```

style.css file:

```
.borderBlack {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Riiight, so without `style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}`, it won't even display. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, please mark answer as correct if it is fine for you, thank you.

Comment: Defining `style` works in plain React.js but it doesn't work in Typescript. In typescript I'm getting the error "No overload matches this call" corresponding to `style`, any ideas?. `Property 'style' does not exist on type ...'`